# pass a value to the state from the component for the object key in the array react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a state with an array of objects:

```
const [Value, setValue] = useState([{ Width: null, Length: null }, { Width: null, Length: null }])
```

And also, I have a component from which I want to get the value for `Value` using `setValue`.

Here is the code:

```
const [Value, setValue] = useState([{ Width: null, Length: null }, { Width: null, Length: null }])

export function SimpleComponent({ Width, setWidth, Length, setLength }) {
  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="number"
        value={Width || ""}
        onChange={event => setWidth(event.target.value)}
      />
      <input
        type="number"
        value={Length || ""}
        onChange={event => setLength(event.target.value)}
      />
    </>
)}

{Value.map((item, i) => {
    return (
      <div key={i}>
        <SimpleComponent
          Width={item.Width}
          setWidth={???}
          Length={item.Length}
          setLength={???}
        />
      </div>
    )
  })
}
```

And I need to specify the `Width` and `Length` value for the current component `SimpleComponent` in the attributes `setWidth` and `setLength`, specified with "???" signs in the code.

I tried to solve this in some ways, but without success.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you can write 2 functions, one for length and one for width

```js
{Value.map((item, i) => {
    return (
      <div key={i}>
        <SimpleComponent
          Width={item.Width}
          Length={item.Length}
          setWidth={(newValue) => {
            setValue([
                ...Value.slice(0, i),
                { ...Value[i], width: newValue },
                ...Value.slice(i+1)
            ])
          }}
          setLength={(newValue) => {
            setValue([
              ...Value.slice(0, i),
              { ...Value[i], length: newValue },
              ...Value.slice(i+1)
            ])
          }}
        />
      </div>
    )
  })
}
```

Or you can combine these into one single function

```js
setDimension=(newValue, i, property) => {
  setValue([
    ...Value.slice(0, i),
    { ...Value[i], [property]: newValue },
    ...Value.slice(i+1)
  ])
}
 
{Value.map((item, i) => {
    return (
      <div key={i}>
        <SimpleComponent
          Width={item.Width}
          setWidth={(newValue) => setDimension(newValue, i, "width")}
          Length={item.Length}
          setLength={(newValue) => setDimension(newValue, i, "length")}
        />
      </div>
    )
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Your code works fine, but my fault I didn't fully specify the code and thought to just shorten the code. But I will have one more value `Length`. I have updated the code. Sorry. Thank you!

Comment: Updated my answer too

Answer (score 0):

You need to define function that, when a new width should be set at index i in the `Value` array, copies the previous array and replaces the element at index i with a new entry.

```js
const setWidthAtIndex = (value, i) = setValue(
    value => value?.map(
        (width, j) => i === j ? {width: value} : width)
);

{Value.map((item, i) => {
    return (
      <div key={i}>
        <SimpleComponent
          Width={item.width}
          setWidth={e => setWidthAtIndex(e, i)}
        />
      </div>
    )
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define your functions like this:

```
const setWidth = (newWidth: number, index?: number) => {
  setValue(current =>
    current.map((currentValue, j) => {
      if (!index || index === j) {
        return { ...currentValue, Width: newWidth }
      }

      return currentValue
    })
  )
}

const setLength = (newLength: number, index?: number) => {
  setValue(current =>
    current.map((currentValue, j) => {
      if (!index || index === j) {
        return { ...currentValue, Length: newLength }
      }

      return currentValue
    })
  )
}
```

Then render components like this:

```
{Value.map((item, i) => {
  return (
    <div key={i}>
      <SimpleComponent
        Width={item.Width}
        setWidth={(newWidth) => setWidth(newWidth, i)}
        Length={item.Length}
        setLength={(newLength) => setLength(newLength, i)}
      />
    </div>
  );
})}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Your code works fine, but my fault I didn't fully specify the code and thought to just shorten the code. But I will have one more value `Length`. I have updated the code. Sorry. Thank you!

Comment: Updated answer to what I think you mean. Is Length the height of the box?

Comment: "Is Length the height of the box?" - yes